# Map update history

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to access to the offline map version history ?

I'm using the MapLoader "performMapUpdates" to install versions, and it's working fine, but we recently had unusual data usage (>1Gb) and I would like to know what map updates have been applied and their sizes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are an official customer, just request it from TCS for the map data package release notes.